# Binary file layout reference

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, file, binary

Where are some good sources of information on binary file layout structures?

If I wanted to pull in a `BTrieve` index file, parse `MP3` headers, etc. Where does one get reliable information?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a general information source for this kind of information.  I always just search on google or wikipedia for that particular file type.  The binary file layout structure information should be included.

For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure">MP3 file layout structure